# c# WebApi: HTTP 200 on local host but 400/401 on remote host with same user

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I've written a simple WebAPI Service (hosted with OWIN in a Windows Service) and put the **[Authorize]** attribute on the POST-method. As I understand, only "known" users can now access the service (don't worry, I know, *all known users* is not really safe yet).

My test client works fine so far **when the host and the client are located on the same machine** (f.ex. my workstation). However when I deploy the service on a server machine, and try again to call the service, I get a HTTP 400 failure when using the System.Net.Http.HttpClient and set httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials=true, or a HTTP 401 when I use System.Net.WebClient and set webClient.UseDefaultCredentials=True.

So it seems the authentication mechanism acts different depending if the service is hosted local or remote.

For test reason I've also tried to set the credential explicit with user and password, but with exactly the same result.

However, what do I miss here? Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify the machine keys.

If the authorization server and the resource server are not on the same computer, the OAuth middleware will use the different machine keys to encrypt and decrypt bearer access token. In order to share the same private key between both projects, we add the same machinekey setting in both web.config files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Comment: True! I've used **AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication** on the **HttpListener** where I've missinterpreted the documentation. I thought when **Negotiate** **_fails_**, **NTLM** would be used. But it was actually meant, when **Negotiate** **_is not supported_**, **NTLM** would be used. Thank you!